# What happens if I change the value of a coupling capacitor in a tube pre-amp

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, vacuum-tube, component-values

I own a Blackheart BH1H amplifier and am considering making modifications to change its sound.

The schematic can be found [here](http://www.sewatt.com/files/sewatt/BLACKHEART%20BH1%20SCHEMATIC.pdf)

One change I have seen suggested is to change the value of C2 from it's current .022uF value to a much smaller 390pF or 500pF cap.

What effect will reducing the value of that capacitor have on the frequency response of the amplifier? Currently there is too much bass response for my taste, will a smaller cap change that? Can the frequency response be calculated easily?

Comment: It'll likely do something but, changing your taste is realistically down to you.

Comment: It looks to me as though reducing C2 by that amount will dramatically reduce the bass response.

Comment: You would be lucky to hear low mid-range much less any bass. Do you not have the usual bass/treble controls?

Comment: There are no tone controls @Sparky256. At least not yet. Just a single volume knob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, reducing the coupling capacitor will reduce the bass-response.

Technically, the capacitor and the output impedance of the tube-stage forms a simple high-pass filter.

Your circuit is very typical: You have the 100k plate resistor. Along with the internal resistance of the triode, that roughly gives an output impedance of 50k Ohm.

Together with the 0.022µF capacitor, you have a cut-off frequency of 1 / (2 * pi * r * C). With your values, that'll give a cut-off at 144Hz.

If you want to reduce the bass response, you can lower the capacitor; however, it is likely much more musical to roll off the bass using a high-shelf filter in front of the amp, and tune it to your liking. The difference is that the high-pass will remove the lowest frequencies, while a shelf filter just attenuates them.

Answer (score 1):

It will raise the low frequency limit (the zero) of the amplifier from around 45Hz to 2kHz if you use 560pF, and higher if you use a smaller value. Simulated values. C2 forms a high-pass filter in conjunction with VR-1 and the output impedance of the preceding stage.

As the lowest frequency a guitar can produce is around 80Hz, it appears to be an idiotic suggestion.